# Перерисовка маркеров в Google Maps API 3

Tags: google-maps-api

Существует порядка 100 маркеров, которые постоянно обновляются через каждые 5 сек (удаляются старые и добавляются заново) при этом все маркеры при перерисовке пропадают и через время появляются, хотелось бы чтоб весь процесс перерисовки проходил незаметно для глаза пользователя
Удаляю :

```
    for (i in gmarkers) {
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
```

вот часть кода, при работе которого происходит мигание

```
var map, marker, gmarkers = [], gmarkers2 = [];

function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.9978, 36.28768);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    DrawObj(-1);

    function DrawObj(param) {
        $.post("Handler.ashx", { date: (new Date()).valueOf() }, function (data) {
            eval(data);
            /*if (param > 0) {
                for (i in gmarkers) { gmarkers2.push(gmarkers[i]); }
            }*/
            for (i in gmarkers) gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
            for (i in data) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude),
                    icon: "img/PAS-GO.png"
                });
                gmarkers.push(marker);
            }
            //for (i in gmarkers2) gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
            //gmarkers2 = [];
        })
    };
    setInterval(function () { DrawObj(2); }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Язык укажите, а то непонятно то ли PHP то ли VB то ли еще что-то

Answer (score 1):

Хм:

1. Маркер должен быть экземпляром объекта маркер, который будет иметь свои свойства и функции. Например ,

   var GMarker = {
              obj: null,
              add: function (obj) { / *Создаем маркер*/; return marker;},
              delete: function () {},
              style: function (obj){}
       };

Все маркеры можно соотнести в массив, где ключом будет ID маркера (произвольный ID. Сами придумайте как им ID задать).

```
var ma = [];
json // объект, в котором содержится информация о маркерах с Вашего сервера.

for (var i = 0; json.length < i; i++) {
      ma[json[id]] = GMarker.add(json['marker']); // Создаем маркеры
}
```

Соответственно, когда нам нужно перерисовать какой-либо маркер, не нужно удалять все, а перерисовать только один, а т.к. нам изместен его ID.... не вижу большой сложности в реализации :)

P.S. Возможно, что-то криво было написано... писал на коленке во время обеда на рабооте :)) но суть передать вроде сумел :)

Answer (score 0):

Если это теже маркеры, то почему просто не обновлять координаты маркера без перерисовки?
А если постоянно новые, то можно так

1. Добавить маркеры на карту, но делать их невидимыми в MarkerOptions {visible:false}
2. Удаляем маркеры с карты gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
3. И затем пробегаем по всем маркерам и делаем gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);